# Is there some way to do the following in SQL?

Tags: sql

Let's imagine that we have these 2 tables:

Table 1, with the column:

```
Field1 
1
3
```

Table 2, with the column:

```
Field1
2
4
```

(Well they could also be called in any other way, but I want to represent that the type of table1.field1 is the same as table2.field1).

Would it be possible to do a SQL query that would return the following?

[1,2,3,4], I mean the numbers ordered by any criteria I would want but that criteria aplying to both tables. As far as I know ORDER BY can just ORDER by the values of a column, not by a general criteria like "from lower to higher number. And even if it could I believe the SELECT instruction can't fuse columns. I mean I think the best I could achieve with that instruction would be to get something like [(1,2),(1,4),(3,2),(3,4)] and later work on it, but this can be painful with lots of results.

And the application needs fields to be on different tables, I cannot merge them.

Any idea about how to deal with this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit:

Oh, it was much easier than what I thought, with that instruction is not something hard to achieve.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You should mark one of the answers below as the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `UNION` statement is for.  It lets you combine two `SELECT` statements into the same resultset:

```
SELECT Field1
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT Field1
FROM Table2

ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: The field in table2 is called Field1 not Field2

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from
(
  select field1 as field_value from table1
  union
  select field2 as field_value from table2

)
order by field_value asc
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ment to put parathesis! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you do `union all`

Like below:

```
Select field 1
from 
   (Select field 1 from Table 1
      Union 
    select field 1 from table 2)
order by field 1
```

Use `union` or `Union all` based on your need to repeat elements in both the tables or not.